# Promotional Discounts of a Specific Brand in Magento

Tags: magento, rule, promotions

I need help, supposed that I have a product brands in Magento and I want it to add special discounts on a specific date until its expiration date. My Question is how do I set it up on Magento's Backend as well as to add the product with disruptors.

***EX.
Product Name: Kia
Discount: 20%
Target: All customer except retailer***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these Steps in Magento's Admin Panel

1) Go to Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules -> Add New Rule

Product Discount 20%
Active
Main Website
Notlogged in, General, Employees
From & To Date

Conditions
Brand is Kia

Actions
By Percentage of the original price
20
No
Yes

2) Adding Disruptors on the Product

Setting up the Configurable Product

Catalog -> Manage Products
Select SKU (Configurable(Type))
Select All (Selection of one by one is prefer)
Actions -> Update Attribute
Attributes -> Higlight Percentage
20%

Comment: Thanks! That's a big help. The Promotional Code is now working as well as the disruptors. Many Thanks

Comment: You're Always Welcome. :)